# listpicker-populate lstPicker2 based on the selection on lstPicker1

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

i am implementing listpicker in my project.
The scenario is when i select an item from lstPicker1, the lstPicker2 items should be changed based on the selection

Here is the lstPicker1 Selection Changed event:

```
private void lstPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstPicker1 != null)
        {
            switch (lstPicker1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    lstPicker2.ItemsSource = CreateList(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and its going to below code,

```
private List<string[]> CreateList(int opt)
    {
   List<string> strLst = new List<string>();
         if (opt==1)
              {
                  String[] str = new String[] { "Option1", "Option2" };
                   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                      {
                         String str1 = str[i];
                         strLst.Add(str1);                               
                      }
                        return strLst;

            }

       if (opt==2)
              {
                  String[] str = new String[] { "Option3", "Option4", "Option5" };
                   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                      {
                         String str1 = str[i];
                         strLst.Add(str1);                               
                      }
                        return strLst;

            }
        }
```

But unfortunately its throwing out error @   **return strLst;** (Error: cannot implicitly convert string to string[])

Please let me know, what i missed on the above coding or if there is something wrong in my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `CreateList` return type is `List<string[]>` which basically is a list of arrays of string values while you are trying to return a list of strings.

Just change the signature of the `CreateList` method to the following:

```
private List<string> CreateList(int opt)
```

**Remarks on the code:**

I actually do not see any reason why are you creating an array of strings and the you are filling your list in the cycle. Just in case - you can create a list of items in the same way as you are creating an array.

You may want to read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) on msdn, the part on **Collection initializers**

Below is alternative implementation of the `CreateList` method which takes much less lines of code:

```
private List<string> CreateList(int opt)
{
     if (opt==1)
     {
          return new List<string> { "Option1", "Option2" }
     }

     if (opt==2)
     {
          return new List<string> { "Option3", "Option4", "Option5" };
     }

     return new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. but unfortunately i am getting an error(CreateList(int):not all code paths return a value) with your alternative approach.

Comment: @ZedProg The problem was that e.g. if the `opt==3` there was nothing returned in the `CreateList` method. Therefore I've added the default value - an empty list if the `opt!=1 && opt!=1`